# Laravel 5, DB::raw, formato de fecha?

Tags: laravel-5

```
DB::raw("(SELECT TO_CHAR(CT_CONTRATO_SERVICIO_ESTADO.D_FECHA,'dd/mm/yyyy')
                FROM ct_contrato_servicio_estado
                WHERE N_ID_CONTRATO_SERVICIO = ct_contrato_servicio.n_id
                ORDER BY  CT_CONTRATO_SERVICIO_ESTADO.D_FECHA  DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) fecha
```

Tengo el siguiente codigo para obtener una fecha en formato: `dd/mm/yy`
pero me devuelve en: `03\/12\/1986`, cual es el problema? Gracias

Comment: "03\/12\/1986" con esos caracteres me devuelve

Answer (score 0):

la solucion es la siguiente, como utilizo postman habia que marcar en la opcion que esta en azul y no la que esta en rojo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero les sirva a otras personas

Comment: y por que es esa la solución???